# Restarting a Django application running on Apache + mod_python

Tags: python, django, mod-python

I'm running a Django app on Apache + mod_python. When I make some changes to the code, sometimes they have effect immediately, other times they don't, until I restart Apache. However I don't really want to do that since it's a production server running other stuff too. Is there some other way to force that?

Just to make it clear, since I see some people get it wrong, I'm talking about a *production* environment. For development I'm using Django's development server, of course.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If possible, you should switch to mod_wsgi. This is now the [recommended way](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/) to serve Django anyway, and is much more efficient in terms of memory and server resources.

In mod_wsgi, each site has a `.wsgi` file associated with it. To restart a site, just `touch` the relevant file, and only that code will be reloaded.

Comment: I'm a bit scared of this XXgi things after all the trouble I had with FastCGI (sure, it was Lighttpd, but still): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393637/django-fastcgi-randomly-raising-operationalerror. Didn't know wsgi is the recommended way to deploy Django now. It used to be mod_python, right? Anyway, I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: s/this things/these things/ :)

Comment: As noted elsewhere, you must use mod_wsgi daemon mode to get feature whereby a reload will occur when WSGI script file is touched.

Comment: @ibz: mod_wsgi is so different from fastcgi that they are not comparable in any way.

Comment: Note that (as Graham Dumpleton mentions below) the touch-.wsgi-file-to-restart only works in daemon mode, not embedded mode.

Answer (score 4):

As others have suggested, use mod_wsgi instead. To get the ability for automatic reloading, through touching the WSGI script file, or through a monitor that looks for code changes, you must be using daemon mode on UNIX. A slight of hand can be used to achieve same on Windows when using embedded mode. All the details can be found in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce number of connections to 1 by setting "MaxRequestsPerChild 1" in your httpd.conf file. But do it only on test server, not production.

or

If you don't want to kill existing connections and still restart apache you can restart it "gracefully" by performing "apache2ctl gracefully" - all existing connections will be allowed to complete.

Comment: "apache2ctl gracefully" sounds like a neat thing. Will definitely look into that, even though it's not exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score -1):

Use a test server included in Django. (like `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`) It will do most things you would need during development. The only drawback is that it cannot handle simultaneous requests with multi-threading.

I've heard that there is a trick that setting Apache's max instances to 1 so that every code change is reflected immediately--but because you said you're running other services, so this may not be your case.

Comment: Thats "MaxRequestsPerChild 1" set in httpd.conf as told by zdmytriv, but DO NOT do this for site handling any load.