# Django Multiprocessing oddity

Tags: python, django, multithreading, multiprocessing, multiprocess

In using ./manage.py shell to exercise some code, I've come across something I don't understand.

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 11 2012, 08:34:23)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from multiprocessing import Process
>>> from django.core.management import call_command
>>> p = Process(target=call_command("processphoto", 1000))
Successfully populated photo "1000"  (This is output from my processphoto command)
>>>
```

I never get the opportunity to do a `p.start()` or set any other variables on the process.  It appears to execute on instantation.  When I try to use the code in my view, I don't appear to get multiple processes spawning at all, everything remains on the one core.

What am I doing wrong, or misunderstanding?  I want to generate separate `manage.py processphoto` commands in separate processes to fully utilize the multi-core server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call_command(...)` calls the function. Instead, pass the function object, `call_command`, and its arguments separately to `Process`:

```
 p = Process(target=call_command, args = ("processphoto", 1000))
```

Comment: Doh!  Good lord, you'd think I was some first time newbie...  Thanks.

Comment: No worries. You see this once and know it forever.

Comment: Please note, doing this will copy the database connection between all children, and can cause problems.  I only bring this up since all of my command scripts have some sort of database interaction.

Here is a thread which sheds some light on the problem, and makes some suggestions to help:

[Django multiprocess database connection][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242837/django-multiprocessing-and-database-connections

Comment: The problem you warn about occurs whenever a process is spawned from a module
with an open connection defined in the module's globally namespace.  This
question does not mention any open database connections.  So while your warning
is True, I don't think it has much relevance to the question or answer dealt
with here.