# In Django, How to refresh a database connection of a child process

Tags: python, django

I am running a child process using the python multiprocessing API from a Django view to do some heavy processing in the background.
This worked fine with sqlite but crashed upon moving to PostgreSQL. I figure it has something to do with having one database connection in two processes.
Following [solution to double connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242837/django-multiprocessing-and-database-connections) I tried closing the connection before starting the process and also inside the process.

These changes eliminated the crash but resulted in a failure to persist the data in the data base. I think either there is no reconnection or the connection is somehow faulty.

here is the relevant code calling the process:

```
    db.close_connection()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=Util.processImage, args=(processUtil, img_full_path, snapshot.pk, process_pk))
    process.start()
```

here is the code inside the process:

```
import sys, traceback, json

from django.db import connection

from datetime import datetime

from yeast_libraries.models import YeastPlateStack_Model, PlateSnapshot_Model, LocusAnalysis_Model,\
    StorageLocation_Model, YeastLibrary_Model, SnapshotProcess_Model

from mediums.models import Batch_Model


from image_analysis.image_processor import ImageAnalysisControler

from yeast_libraries import db_manager


class Util:

def processImage(self, img_full_path, snapshot_pk, process_pk):



    print('process_pk: ', process_pk)



    try:
        snapshot_process = SnapshotProcess_Model.objects.get(pk=process_pk)
        print(snapshot_process.status)

        status = 'bussy'

        print('processImage:', datetime.now())
        sys.stdout.flush()


        snapshot = PlateSnapshot_Model.objects.get(pk = snapshot_pk)
        imageAnalysisControler = ImageAnalysisControler()
    #             print('a:', a)

        processed_image_path = img_full_path[:-5] + '_p.jpg'

        global grid

        print('process image: getting analysis')



        #grid = imageAnalysisControler.analyzeYeastPlateImage(img_full_path, processed_image_path)
        grid = imageAnalysisControler.analyzeYeastPlateImage('image_analysis/plates/384_0001.jpg', processed_image_path)

        print('process image: got analysis')

        snapshot.processed_image_path = processed_image_path

        for cell in grid['grid']:

            locus = LocusAnalysis_Model.objects.create(
                area_scaled = cell['area_scaled'], 
                is_empty = cell['is_empty'], 
                column = cell['column'],  
                row = cell['row'], 
                ratio = cell['ratio'], 
                center_x = cell['center_x'], 
                center_y = cell['center_y']
            )
            snapshot.analysis.add(locus)

        snapshot.save()

        sys.stdout.flush()

        status = 'completed' 

    except Exception:
        print('exception: ', sys.exc_info)
        traceback.print_exc()
        status = 'failed' 

    snapshot_process.status = status
    snapshot_process.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying several things I decided to workaround using the psycopg2 binding for python and used an altogether different connection and SQL