# How to refresh django connection when inserting in SQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following pattern in my code:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO main_catalog (1,'mark')")
conn.commit()

item = Catalog.objects.get(pk=1)
item.do_something()
```

However, I get an error saying that `Catalog.DoesNotExist` for id=1, even though I can see it in the database. How do I get the ORM to recognize this new value so I can then query it? (Note that I must use raw sql for certain reasons.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following pattern works to reset the connection and get a 'fresh cursor':

```
from django import db

try:
    item = Catalog.objects.get(pk=1)
except Catalog.DoesNotExist:
    db.close_connection()
    item = Catalog.objects.get(pk=1)
```

This question may also be of use: [Django multiprocessing and database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242837/django-multiprocessing-and-database-connections).

Comment: This answer is now obsolete. There is no such function in django.db anymore. There is a close_old_connections() though which seems safe to call, maybe it does what we want here.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @boxed, the accepted answer no longer works, however the `close_old_connections()` function he mentions worked for me. I.e.:

```
from django import db
db.close_old_connections()
```