# What is the cause of a sporadic ORA-12599: TNS:cryptographic checksum mismatch?

Tags: database, oracle

In our production environment there are sometimes peaks of ORA-12599 errors the connection works otherwise.

The description is not quite clear to me.

> **Cause:** The data received is not the same as the data sent.
>
> **Action:**
>   Attempt the transaction again. If error persists, check (and correct)
>   the integrity of your physical connection.

https://www.oraexcel.com/database-oracle-11gR2-ORA-12599

Does that mean there is a problem with my **network cable**? Or any other Hardware?

Because our DBA said the error can be caused by a **configuration issue** on the client side.

**Edit:**
It started without any changes on the client or server side. And there are spikes. 80 errors in an hour and then no errors for 4 hours while the load is more or less constant

Answer (score 0):

It can mean a mismatch in how the client and the server are wishing to communicate (in encrypted fashion). For example, trying to connect to an 11g database with 10g JDBC drivers will get this because the encryption implementation changed between these versions.

Check your local (ie, client) sqlnet.ora file - you may need to opt for a different method or change the order of them.

The error can be typically be ignored (its informational) but using the latest drivers will normally resolve the issue.

Comment: i assume the error would happen on each statement if the configuration was off?

Answer (score 0):

We had sporadic ORA-12599 errors and also ORA-24300 ("bad value for mode") in a Python web app using Flask and uwsgi. It turned out to be caused by multiple worker processes writing and reading to/from the same TCP connection to the DB, giving chaotic communications on the socket.

In our setup this was caused by creating the TCP connections to the DB before uwsgi forked the workers, and the file descriptors being inherited. We fixed this by using uwgsi's [lazy-apps mode](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html#preforking-vs-lazy-apps-vs-lazy).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242837/django-multiprocessing-and-database-connections).